# Jackson marshal/unmarshal behaving differently in jaxrs wildfly 15

Tags: jboss, jackson, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

To give a brackground, We are in the process of migrating our application from JBoss 7 to Wildfly 15 as part of that we updated all dependencies of FasterXML (2.9.5), RestEasy (3.6.2.final) to the version that Wildfly 15 modules support.
We also updated the code base to use fasterxml instead of codehaus. Now that compilation and deployment is successful. When are we triggering a REST request through postman there are certain parameters are not able to de-serialize. The example is as follows.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "User", propOrder = {
    "userInfo",
    "profiles",
    "groups"
})
public class User extends NfvdResource implements IUser {
    
    @XmlElement(name = "user-info", required = true)
    protected UserInfo userInfo;
    protected Profiles profiles;
    protected Groups groups;
..
..
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Groups", propOrder = {
    "group"
})
public class Groups implements IGroups {
    
    private List<Group> group;
 @Override
    public List<Group> getGroup() {
        if (group == null) {
            group = new ArrayList<Group>();
        }
        return this.group;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Groups [group=" + group + "]";
    }

}

@XmlRootElement( name = "user")
public interface IUser extends IProfiles, IGroups {

    @JsonProperty("user-info")
    public UserInfo getUserInfo();

    @JsonIgnore
    public Profiles getProfiles();

    @JsonIgnore
    public Groups getGroups();

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "profiles")
public interface IProfiles {
    
    @JsonProperty("profiles")
    public List<Profile> getProfile();
}

public interface IGroups {

    @JsonProperty("groups")
    public List<Group> getGroup();
}
```

The sample payload is as follows.

```
{
   "user-info":{"username":"dem115","name":"dem115","surname":"dem115","phonenumber":"123546","email":"abc@xyz.com","preferred-language":"en-us","preferred-theme":"light","role":"domain","password":"xxxx","public-key":"TBD"
},
   "profiles":[
            {"type":"domain","name":"administrator","description":"","operations":[]},
            {"type":"domain","name":"scriptManager","description":"","operations":[]}
   ],
   "groups":[
      {"domain":"sample.domain","datacenter":null,"organization":null,"tenant":null,"vnf":null,"type":"domain","@uri":"/abc/domains/95b3c440-843e-4163-b737-cc0f273238c1","@internal-id":"xxxxxx-843e-4163-b737-cc0f273238c1"}
   ],
}
```

With the above payload, the `profiles` and `groups` parameters in `user` object is set to null which was not the case with JBoss 7 and jackson1 and relevant configuration.
Are we missing some configuration as part of migration is what we are not sure.

To make it work we comeup with the following workaround. Just adding @JsonUnwrapped annotation on to `profiles` and `groups` field marshalling and unmarshalling is working.

```
@JsonUnwrapped
protected Profiles profiles;
@JsonUnwrapped
    protected Groups groups;
```

We are not sure what is missing in migration that we working earlier. Also we are not sure about the side effects of this annotation.
Another problem here is that we have similar kind pattern across the application (around 250 java files). So we are worried it would impact on functionality.

Is there something we are missing fundamentally? Could someone shed some light here? We are reaching our to this forum after trying to investigate for over a week.

**Another important point to mention is that we are also migrating java 1.7 to jdk11 as part of this process.**

Thankyou in advance for your help.

Comment: That's not [valid JSON](https://jsonlint.com) you posted.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to customize the way Jackson is serializing your beans in json.
For instance, in a CDI containter (like Wildfly):

```
@Provider
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class CustomizedJsonProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider {

    public CustomizedJsonProvider() {
        super();
        super.setMapper( initMapper() );
    }
    
    private static ObjectMapper initMapper() {
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)          
             .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)                                              
            .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
         return mapper; 
    }
    
}
```

See all features [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html)